# How to zoom in on a google data studio line chart

Tags: looker-studio

so this chart represents my p/l during a day! X axis is created using a timestamp column and Y axis is created using a p/l column in google sheets. Now, how do I remove the blank space from 12am to 6pm. This chart represents my p/l during a day when Im trading stocks.! I only trade from 7pm to 10pm hence I don't want every single hour of the day!
I got the desired output by applying a timestamp filter but it could only be used for a specific date! Is there any way to zoom in on the blue part? or any filter to hide specific hours?        [image]

I'd grateful if you guys could help!

Comment: Update: Just found a new way to get the desired output, make a new drilldown dimension using timestamp's minute! This would zoom in the chart based on minuted!

Answer (score 0):

if you're using Time Series chart, you can go to Style-> find x-axis part-> under Range you can click the dropdown and select Range by Data.

[image]

Hope it helps!